How to use NVM-windows to switch node versions without requiring admin rights each time?
The build plan of my application includes a legacy component which relies on an older version of node than the rest. How can I switch node versions using NVM-windows without requiring admin rights each time?
Currently my build scripts get interrupted by a windows prompt halfway through, they can't be run unattended.
nvm use ... # this opens a windows prompt for admin rights


I have not tried it myself but see if this can help you: Install NVM without Admin Rights

This was helpful but it did not fully solve my problem

NVM-windows can be used without requiring admin rights after setting it up as follows:

Uninstall NVM-windows and/or nodejs if they are already present
Download and run the latest NVM-windows installer (or install it manually without admin rights)
For the NVM installation path, choose a folder within the user directory
For the Node.js symlink path, choose a path within the user directory as well and complete the installation
Enable "Developer Mode" in Windows 10+

Developer Mode allows NVM to manage symlinks without admin privileges.
